# Definition of Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In *Linear Algebra Done Right*, Axler defines, in Chapter 10, an invertible matrix as:

> A square matrix $A$ is called invertible if there is a square matrix $B$ of the same size such that $AB=BA=I$, and we call $B$ an inverse of $A$.

Question: Why does he include ***same size*** in his definition? Won’t it be automatically implied if $AB=BA=I$?
Even [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) mentions of the same size.

I thought that we make mathematical definitions as concise as possible.

Comment: If we did not say $B$ was of the same size as $A$, we would have to write "...if there is a square matrix $B$ such that $AB$ and $BA$ are defined and $AB=BA=I$...". In general, it is inadvisable to make statements about things (here, the products $AB$ and $BA$) if you are not even sure that they are well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is superfluous, as are the two *square* qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You need the same size to make sure that $AB$ and $BA$ are actually defined.

Comment: Doesn’t saying that $AB=BA=I$ already imply that these are defined?

Comment: You can have both $AB$ and $BA$ defined without $A$ and $B$ being square, but then $AB$ and $BA$ cannot be _equal_. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not necessary to mention in the definition, it does not hurt either. It will make the reader consider the relevant situation (two square matrices of the same size), so why not help the reader?

Do note that non-square matrices can produce an identity matrix when multiplied together *in one order only*, as in the following example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-8 & 0 & -9 \\ -7 & 0 & -8\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-8 & 9 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 7 & -8\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
In such cases, when you multiply the matrices in the opposite order, like $\begin{bmatrix}-8 & 9 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 7 & -8\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-8 & 0 & -9 \\ -7 & 0 & -8\end{bmatrix}$, the result will *not* be an identity matrix (you can prove that as an exercise).